# Advanced search with ajax, php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, advanced-search

I'm building an advanced search with ajax, php and mysql. below is the working code for the search form (html) the AJAX call and the php script that handles the request. However, the issue i'm facing is how to make a dynamic mysql query.

For example if the user searches "Hilton Hotel" in the search input, selects "accommodation" as the `industry_types` and "Hotel" as the `sub_industry_type` and selects "London" as the city. How can I write a query that will take all of these inputs into consideration?

Please note: in the search.php i have included the query for handling a keyword submitted in the `user_search_input` input.

Index.php (HTML):

```
<form class="user_search_form" action="" method="post"> 
<input type="text" class="user_search_input" placeholder="search" />    

<select class="industry_types" name="industry_types" id="industry_types">
<option value="">Select an industry</option>
<option value="Accommodation">Accommodation</option>
<option value="Food_Drink">Food & Drink</option>
<option value="Entertainment">Entertainment</option>
<option value="Retail">Retail</option>      
<option value="Telecommunications">Telecommunications</option>  
<option value="Transportation">Transportation</option>      
</select>   


<select class="Accommodation sub_industry_type" name="Accommodation" id="sub_industry_type">
<option value="0">Select Accommodation subcategory</option>
<option value="Bed and Breakfasts">Bed and Breakfasts</option>
<option value="Hotel">Hotels</option>
<option value="Hotel">Hostels</option>
<option value="Resturant">Resorts</option>
<option value="Serviced apartments">Serviced apartments</option>
</select>

<select class="Food_Drink sub_industry_type" name="Food_Drink" id="sub_industry_type">
<option value="0">Select Cuisine subcategory</option>
<option value="Resturant">Restaurants</option>
<option value="Cafes">Cafes</option>
<option value="Bars and Pubs">Bars and Pubs</option>
<option value="Tourist Agency">Night clubs</option>
</select>   


<select class="Entertainment sub_industry_type" name="Entertainment" id="sub_industry_type">
<option value="0">Select Entertainment subcategory</option>
<option value="Performing Arts">Performing Arts</option>
<option value="Cinemas">Cinemas</option>
<option value="Resorts and Casinos">Resorts and Casinos</option>
<option value="Amusement Parks and Attractions">Amusement Parks</option>    
<option value="Museums">Museums</option>
<option value="Outdoor activities">Outdoor activities</option>
<option value="Media and Entertainment Other">Entertainment Other</option>
</select>

<select class="Retail sub_industry_type" name="Retail" id="sub_industry_type">
<option value="0">Select Retail subcategory</option>        
<option value="Beer, Wine and Liquor Stores">Beer, Wine and Liquor Shops</option>
<option value="Clothing and Shoe Stores">Clothing and Shoe Shops</option>
<option value="Electronic Shops">Electronic Shops </option>
<option value="Jewelry, Luggage, and Accessories">Jewelry, Luggage, and Accessories</option>
<option value="Sporting Goods, Hobby, Books and Music Stores">Sporting Goods, Hobby, Books and Music Stores</option>
<option value="Internet Businesses">Internet Businesses</option>    
<option value="Retail Others">Retail Others</option>
</select>

<select class="Telecommunications sub_industry_type" name="Telecommunications" id="sub_industry_type">
<option value="0">Select Telecommunications subcategory</option>    
<option value="Telephone Service Providers and Carriers">Telephone Service Providers</option>
<option value="Telecommunications Other">Telecommunications Other</option>
</select>       

<select class="Transportation sub_industry_type" name="Transportation" id="sub_industry_type">
<option value="0">Select Transportation subcategory</option>    
<option value="Car Rental">Car Rentals</option>
<option value="Taxi, Buses and Transit Systems">Taxi Services</option>
<option value="Travel Agents">Travel Agents</option>    
</select>               

<select name="select_city" class="select_city">
<option value="">City</option>
<option value="">London</option>
<option value="">New York</option>
<option value="">Paris</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="search"  class="search_btn" />  
</form>
```

Index.php (AJAX):

```
$('.user_search_form').submit(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();    

var $search_input = $('.user_search_input').val();  
var $industry_general = $('.industry_types').val(); 
var $industry_spesific = $('.sub_industry_type').val(); 
var $selected_city = $('.select_city').val();   


var url = "search.php"; 

        $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        type: "POST", 
        url: url, 
        data:{search_input: $search_input, industry_general: $industry_general, industry_spesific: $industry_spesific, selected_city: $selected_city},  
        dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
        success: function(date){                    
        $('#search_results').html(date); 


        }
    })
});
```

search.php (The issue):

```
<?php include 'includes/db_connect.php'; 

$search_input = $_POST['search_input'];
$industry_general = $_POST['industry_general'];
$industry_spesific = $_POST['industry_spesific'];
$selected_city = $_POST['selected_city'];

if(!empty($search_input)){

$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE company_name LIKE :company_name OR company_keywords LIKE :company_keywords OR company_city LIKE :company_city OR company_email LIKE :company_email");

    $sql->bindValue(':company_name', '%' . $search_input . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);    
    $sql->bindValue(':company_keywords', '%' . $search_input . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);    
    $sql->bindValue(':company_city', '%' . $search_input . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);    
    $sql->bindValue(':company_email', '%' . $search_input . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);   


    if($sql->execute()) {
       $sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }   

}

elseif(!empty($industry_general)){

           // if industry_general is not empty   
}

elseif(!empty($industry_spesific)){

          // if industry_spesific is not empty      
}

elseif(!empty($selected_city)){

         // if selected_city is not empty 
}?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic? Your code seems fine.

Comment: There is a lot of unnecessary code here. Regardless, I cannot really help you with your problem.

Comment: @learner my code is fine. it all works, but i'm not sure where to go from here. when i say dynamic, if you look at the php file, what is the next query? that will effect the results of the first. then the 3rd, 4th. that's what's confusing me.

Comment: Do prepare statement after building all logical operations. For example: 
Make some string variable $sql. Then if some condition do concatenation for those $sql. And finally prepare and execute your query

Comment: @EvanCarslake Then why say anything?? You're right there is a lot unnecessary code, i'm just trying to give a complete picture.

Comment: @AlexSlipknot Yes, that sounds perfect. do you know of any good resource/example?

Comment: @bob, I don't think you need more that you know. You're already did it. Just write a little bit more code.
`if (isset($ololo)) { $sql .= ' AND city = :city'; }`

Answer (score 2):

How about this snippet?

```
// columns that should contain either of the search_input words
$searchTermCols = [
    'company_name',
    'company_keywords',
    'company_city',
    'company_email'
];

$data = $_POST; // copy $_POST array to a variable so you can safely alter keys/values
$searchInput = $data['search_input']; // tmp store search_input so you can unset it for the rest of the code
unset($data['search_input']); // unset unnecessary keys (if you have any). like in your case you want to do different stuff with that key=>value
//unset($data['some_other_unwanted_input_doing_other_stuff']); // or another one
$searchInputParts = preg_split('/\s+/', $searchInput); // explode by whitespace
$searchInput = implode('|',$searchInputParts); // for REGEXP search in mysql to search each word occurrence in a column

foreach($data as $key=>$val) { // loop through copied array
    $sqlParts1[] = $key.' LIKE :'.$key;
}
foreach($searchTermCols as $key) { // loop through columns that should contain either of the words
    $sqlParts2[] = $key.' REGEXP :'.$key;
}

$andParts = implode(' AND ',$sqlParts1); // these options must exists in the columns
$orParts = implode(' OR ',$sqlParts2); // these options must exists in the columns

$qryStr = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ";
$qryStr .= "($andParts) AND ($orParts)"; // concatenate both similar but different queries and append to query
$sql = $dbh->prepare($qryStr);

foreach($data as $key=>$val) {
    $sql->bindValue(':'.$key, '%' . trim($val) . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
foreach($searchTermCols as $key) {
    $sql->bindValue(':'.$key, $searchInput, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}

if($sql->execute()) {
    $sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

UPDATE

You can copy $_POST to another variable and unset keys you dont want in the query. See first two added lines and the $data variable set to loop through.

UPDATE 2 Important..

Your form input's name attributes need to match your database table's columns. So for example:

```
<input type="text" name="company_name" id="company_name">
```

If your db table's column name is "company_name".

UPDATE 3

For fun i added the requirements explained in your comment. I do not have your table structure so i did not test it...

Comment: I get the response: "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'search_input'" , I love the code though, it's so simple but complex.

Comment: I think it's because i'm passing the element values separately in the ajax call.

Comment: It depends what you want to do with the value of search_input. You can exclude it from your foreach loop as seen in the edit of my answer. But maybe you can explain what you want to do with search_input.

Comment: so I just add as many `$data = $_POST; unset($data['search_input']);` as i have post variables?

Comment: `search_input` is searching the database based on the user entered keyword(s).

Comment: No. Only once you set `$data = $_POST;`. If you have inputs in your form that you dont want to include in the search query, you can exclude them by unsetting the key in the $data array right before looping through it. `unset($data['some_input_i_dont_want_in_query']); unset($data['some_other_input_i_dont_want_in_query']);`. What db column(s) is the value of search_input supposed to be found in?

Comment: search_input is supposed to be found in cols company_name, company_keywords, company_city, company_email.

Comment: Please have a look at my edit. I added comments to help you understand the code. It is pretty much scalable.

Comment: Note this this line `$qryStr .= "($andParts) AND ($orParts)";` instead of `$qryStr .= "($andParts) OR ($orParts)";` because you are searching for all of the terms in each column AND for options in each column. Not  either. I cannot/want not test the code since i dont have your shema..